# Warnings while synthesising, not able to run ISim

Tags: verilog, xilinx, xilinx-ise

```
module SimpleDDS(DAC_clk, DAC_data);
input DAC_clk;
output [9:0] DAC_data;

// let's create a 16 bits free-running binary counter
reg [15:0] cnt;
always @(posedge DAC_clk) cnt <= cnt + 16'h1;

// and use it to generate the DAC signal output
wire cnt_tap = cnt[7];     // we take one bit out of the counter (here bit 7 = the 8th bit)
assign DAC_data = {10{cnt_tap}};   // and we duplicate it 10 times to create the 10-bits DAC value 
                                     // with the maximum possible amplitude
endmodule
```

> WARNING:Xst:2677 - Node  of sequential type is unconnected in
>   block .
>
> WARNING:Xst:2677 - Node  of sequential type is unconnected in
>   block .
>
> WARNING:Xst:2677 - Node  of sequential type is unconnected in
>   block .
>
> WARNING:Xst:2677 - Node  of sequential type is unconnected in
>   block .
>
> WARNING:Xst:2677 - Node  of sequential type is unconnected in
>   block .
>
> WARNING:Xst:2677 - Node  of sequential type is unconnected in
>   block .
>
> WARNING:Xst:2677 - Node  of sequential type is unconnected in
>   block .
>
> WARNING:Xst:2677 - Node cnt_15 of sequential type is unconnected in
>   block SimpleDDS.

Could someone help me out with this warning? I am not able to run ISim because of the same.

```
module test_SimpleDDs_v;

    // Inputs
    reg DAC_clk;

    // Outputs
    wire [9:0] DAC_data;

    // Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
    SimpleDDS uut (
        .DAC_clk(DAC_clk), 
        .DAC_data(DAC_data)
    );

    initial begin
        // Initialize Inputs
        DAC_clk = 0;

        // Wait 100 ns for global reset to finish
        #100;

        // Add stimulus here
        DAC_clk = ~ DAC_clk;
        #100;
        DAC_clk = ~ DAC_clk;
    end

endmodule
```

Comment: Focus on running the simulation first. In what way are you "not able" to run ISIM?

Comment: @BrianDrummond : i wrote a test bench which changes the clock but my square wave is not generated as expected, i get 'x' in all the cnt registers

Comment: Sounds like you're running ISIM just fine. How are you resetting `cnt` to a known value at the start of simulation?

Comment: i dont think i am resetting cnt to a know value, can u show me how?

Comment: `    module test_SimpleDDs_v;

     // Inputs
 reg DAC_clk;

 // Outputs
 wire [9:0] DAC_data;

 // Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
 SimpleDDS uut (
  .DAC_clk(DAC_clk), 
  .DAC_data(DAC_data)
 );

 initial begin
  // Initialize Inputs
  DAC_clk = 0;

  // Wait 100 ns for global reset to finish
  #100;
        
  // Add stimulus here
  DAC_clk = ~ DAC_clk;
  #100;
  DAC_clk = ~ DAC_clk;
end

endmodule`

Comment: i have shared my test bench here @BrianDrummond

Answer (score 0):

`cnt[15:8]` are unused.  To eliminate those warning messages, just use an 8-bit counter.

```
reg [7:0] cnt;
always @(posedge DAC_clk) cnt <= cnt + 8'h1;
```

Comment: `
module test_SimpleDDs_v;

     // Inputs
 reg DAC_clk;

 // Outputs
 wire [9:0] DAC_data;

 // Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
 SimpleDDS uut (
  .DAC_clk(DAC_clk), 
  .DAC_data(DAC_data)
 );

 initial begin
  // Initialize Inputs
  DAC_clk = 0;

  // Wait 100 ns for global reset to finish
  #100;
        
  // Add stimulus here
  DAC_clk = ~ DAC_clk;
  #100;
  DAC_clk = ~ DAC_clk;
end

endmodule
`